# Ban an ip automatically after repeated suspicious attempt via .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, http, security, spam-prevention

I've been tracking traffic to my website and lately I have been seeing deliberate attrmpts to find a weak spot, specofically in this case, trying various combinations of http:/// + random file names/extensions

So, if I made a "patter recognizer" that detected various domain searches that did not match any that existed, or even just the http:/// part, how could I trigger an automatic .htaccess block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking odd URLs via .htaccess is pointless as you'll only be blocking things that are already safe.  This could lead to a false sense of security or, worse, bad security where you're only protected in the specific case and not the more general case.

Instead, make sure the server installation is well configured so you don't have to worry about those things.

Comment: Whereas firewalling the perp might actually offer some protection against further attempts. http://www.bashoneliners.com/oneliners/oneliner/217/

Comment: @tripleee, yes, some sort of automated detection of _attackers_ (rather than the _attack_) is very useful, especially for DDoS protection.

Comment: How do you know if your server is "well configured" ? what do you mean by that? I have parameterized binding, only one of my websites has SSL

Comment: That is an exceptionally broad question.  It depends on your OS and exactly what server you're running, what you want it to do, etc., etc.  There are entire companies dedicated to answering that question and pages upon pages of it around the web.  If you have something specific, ask a new question on ServerFault.com.